# Vectorization of raw values to features using Tensorflow Learn (TFLearn)

Tags: python, tensorflow

TFLearn [has a number of useful utilities](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/g3doc/api_docs/python/functions_and_classes/shard1/tf.contrib.learn.LinearClassifier.md) for training linear estimators which can make derivative feature columns, however I'd really like to verify the feature vectorization process by feeding in a single raw example -> and getting a feature vector.

Unfortunately I don't see a way to do this using the TFLearn codebase.

As a (dumb) example with two columns, 'gender' (categorical) and a label:

```
female,98
male,38
```

With the corresponding script:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd 

df_train = pd.read_csv(
    tf.gfile.Open("wide_n_deep/data.csv"),
    names=["gender", "label"],
    skipinitialspace=True)
df_train.label = (df_train.label).astype(int)

gender = tf.contrib.layers.sparse_column_with_keys(
        column_name="gender", 
        keys=["female", "male"])

wide_columns = [gender]
model = tf.contrib.learn.LinearClassifier(
    model_dir="models", 
    feature_columns=wide_columns)

def input_fn(df):
    categorical_cols = {"gender": tf.SparseTensor(
            indices=[[i, 0] for i in range(df["gender"].size)],
            values=df["gender"].values,
            shape=[df["gender"].size, 1])}
    label = tf.constant(df["label"].values)
    return categorical_cols, label

model.fit(input_fn=lambda: input_fn(df_train), steps=100)
```

Question: How do I get the feature vector from this example?

```
example = {"gender" : "female", "label" : 93}  # or a DataFrame row, etc
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Some related and useful methods can be found in its super parent class `_DNNLinearCombinedBaseEstimator`.

For example, `_get_linear_feature_columns`, `_get_dnn_feature_columns`, `dnn_weights_`, `dnn_bias_`, `linear_bias_`, `linear_weights_`, etc.

Comment: Might you have a code example? Also I guess I'm surprised the answer would be methods with leading underscores (private). This is such an important function for a featurizer to do!